# Python - AttributeError: 'List' Object has no attribute 'click'. Selenium. (Picture provided)

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm sure there's something simple I'm not figuring out but I need help with this. I'm trying to select an item within the cell of a table but it's proving difficult. Below is the source:

```
  <div class="clear formrow top_border">
            <div>
<table class="infoGrid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Program Name</th><th scope="col">
                            <img alt="Schedule Type" src="../../../../Resources/images/arrow_black_downward.gif" />
                        </th><th scope="col">Week Of</th><th scope="col">Schedule Distribution</th><th scope="col">Release Date/Time</th><th scope="col">Init Cap</th><th scope="col">CapLift Date/Time</th><th scope="col">Max Cap</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Disney Mainline</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp" class="cls_arw arw_blue" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$lnkSchTyp','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 22, 2017</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchDist" class="cls_arw arw_grey" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$lnkSchDist','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 10, 2017 10:21 AM</td><td>15</td><td>Oct 12, 2017 03:30 PM</td><td>80</td><td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnApp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnApp_Id" value="138" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnApp_Sch_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnApp_Sch_Id" value="48344" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnApp_Grp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnApp_Grp_Id" value="686" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnWk_Strt_Date" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnWk_Strt_Date" value="10/22/2017 00:00:00" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnOffset" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnOffset" value="-300" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnPrivType" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnPrivType" value="e" />
                        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Disney Mainline</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_lnkSchTyp" class="cls_arw arw_blue" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$lnkSchTyp','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 29, 2017</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_lnkSchDist" class="cls_arw arw_grey" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$lnkSchDist','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 17, 2017 06:00 PM</td><td>15</td><td>Oct 19, 2017 03:30 PM</td><td>80</td><td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnApp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnApp_Id" value="138" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnApp_Sch_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnApp_Sch_Id" value="48471" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnApp_Grp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnApp_Grp_Id" value="686" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnWk_Strt_Date" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnWk_Strt_Date" value="10/29/2017 00:00:00" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnOffset" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnOffset" value="-300" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnPrivType" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnPrivType" value="e" />
                        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
    </div>
```

As you can tell since the table hasn't been closed that there are more rows. They look exactly the same except for the id is different. These are the things that I've tried so far:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp")
elem.click()

elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.cls_arw arw_blue")
elem.click()

for row in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.cls_arw arw_blue"):
    cell = row in row.find_elements_by_class_name("cls_arw arw_blue")
    cell.click()

elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cls_arw arw_blue")[-1]
elem.click()
```

The last two things that I tried are because as I pointed out there are more rows to the table that look exactly the same except for the id is different. I wanted to always grab the last blue arrow in the table, but at this point I would be happy to just figure out how to click on any blue arrow. You can see in the sourcecode that the blue arrow has a href. The image of the table on the webpage is below.

[image]

That first blue arrow is the part of the code that is:

```
<td><a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp" class="cls_arw arw_blue" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$lnkSchTyp','')"></a></td>
```

Please let me know if you need more information or if I need to clear something up.

Comment: you are using the findelements (plural form) and calling click method on a list. click should be called on a webelement. Use the singular findelement or retrieve an element from the list and then call click()

Comment: Moreover, after you fix `elem.click()` I'm quite sure that you will get error on `cell.click()`. Because your `cell` seem to be boolean, but not WebElement

Comment: @Grasshopper, sorry...that's a typo. I was using find_element for the first two tries. I would edit, but I'm not sure how to edit.

Comment: @Andersson, what are you seeing that makes you think the cell is boolean?

Comment: @AP1, expression like `something in list` returns `True` or `False`. Did you mean `cell = [row for row in row.find_elements_by_class_name("cls_arw arw_blue")][0]`?

Comment: @AP1 if for the first two times findelement was used then a webelement would be returned if query is correct. Then the error of a list is not right. Is there soneother line where the error is being thrown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' - Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223011/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-click-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: When you get an error message, you need to take a few minutes and search the error message. If you would have done that, you would have found the error and the solution.

Comment: @JeffC, what makes you think that I didn't? I looked at so many of them on here and DID NOT find a solution that worked for me.

Comment: @JeffC, that link you provided didn't help me.

Comment: Then you need to look at it again. You have exactly the same problem as is described in that link with the same solution.

Comment: @JeffC, Ok, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is not right. Your error was:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

because, as was written in the comments, you tried to click on a list and not an object.

I saw that you edited the question. The original was with:

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp")
elem.click()
```

That's why your error.

If you change with:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp")
elem.click()
```

You will see that the error is another.

If you take a look to your element:

```
<a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp" class="cls_arw arw_blue" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$lnkSchTyp','')"></a>
```

There is the attribute **href** that contains the ref to the javascript to execute.

If you want to perform this action, try:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp')
href = elem.get_attribute("href")
print(href)
#href="alert('hello world');"
driver.execute_script(href, elem)
```

Comment: Hey @DurdenP, you're right. I did get a different error when I changed element(s) to element. It threw a NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element. I tried your solution, but I'm receiving the same error. Do you think that since the element is a cell within a table that it's not finding it? I've been looking into xpath, but not sure if I understand it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Going through all the comments/discussions/Answer I think we have over complicated the issue. The error `'List' Object has no attribute 'click'` says it all clear and concise that we are trying to invoke `click()` method on a `List` object which is not supported.

If your requirement was to click on each and every link we would have used `find_elements_by_css_selector` and iterated through the list and clicked on each `WebElement` in the `List`. But as your requirement is to click on the last blue arrow in the table but you haven't provided the `HTML` for that. So let us try to figure out how to click on the first blue arrow.

- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='cls_arw arw_blue'][@id,'ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp']").click()
  ```
- **`css_selector`** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.cls_arw arw_blue[id='ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp']").click()
  ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. When I try this I receive

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//a[@class='cls_arw arw_blue'][@id,'ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp']" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

I edited the source code to show the full div of the table.

Comment: When I try your second solution I get a NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element.