# Click() function not working in python / selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

as you can see I'm starting coding a bot to cop sneakers on SNKRS. I've already coded a few useless things but we don't care. I want the bot to click on the log in button, but at the end when I run the code, it opens Chrome then it opens the nike website but then it doesn't click on the button and I have this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/SNKRS_bot/snkrs bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    loginBtn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/section/div/ul/li[1]/button").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.nike.com/ch/fr/launch?s=upcoming")

time.sleep(3)
loginBtn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/section/div/ul/li[1]/button").click()

time.sleep(6)
driver.quit()
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I couldn't find that the xpath you are looking for at all. Besides, you are calling `find_elements_by_xpath`, which returns a list. Assuming it finds one or more elements that satisfies the xpath, you can't pass a list to the `click` function; you have to pass one of the elements of the list. And rather than use calls to `sleep`, better would be to call `driver.implcitly_wait(6)` at the very beginning. The driver will then wait to up to 6 seconds to find an element but will return much sooner if it finds the element sooner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' - Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223011/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-click-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to your posted question. I did in the end find your button, but it is not clickable without resorting to using JavaScript:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(6) # wait up to 6 seconds to find an element
    driver.get("https://www.nike.com/ch/fr/launch?s=upcoming")
    
    loginBtns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/section/div/ul/li[1]/button")
    if loginBtns:
        #loginBtns[0].click()
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', loginBtns[0])
    else:
        print('Could not find login button.')
finally:
    driver.quit()
```