# XPath 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select a checkbox on the following public webpage using Selenium XPath from Python and click it to change the checked status.

http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fout

For example, the checkbox that I would like to click is located under "Fluxes/Magnitudes" and is named "U".

Upon inspection of this page I built the following XPath to select the checkbox:

```
//*[@type ='checkbox' and @name='U']
```

This returns what I believe to be the correct element, however when I try to run click() on the object it fails with the exception 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

When I look at the functions for this object in a debugger it indeed does not have a click function. How can this be true for a checkbox? Is there a different element that has to be selected?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' - Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223011/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-click-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste your code here, but from the error you getting it's quite clear, that you are using

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@type ='checkbox' and @name='U']')
```

instead of

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type ='checkbox' and @name='U']')
```

`find_elements_by_xpath` method returns a list of web elements.  You can apply `click()` method only on a single element, that's why you should use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type ='checkbox' and @name='U']')
```

or alternatively

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@type ='checkbox' and @name='U']')[0]
```

to get the first (single) element from the returned list

Comment: Thanks, my bad and you are correct.  Copy and paste error from another line of code.