# 'list' object has no attribute 'text' for selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")

#print(driver.title)

#ID, name, class
#ID is unique, but is often missing
#name is not unique, but always exists
#class is not unique
search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "s")
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #return means enter


#wait for a specific thing to exist on the page before we start looking for it
#let our driver to wait for 10 sec until EC.xxx is reached
try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main")) #By.name, By.class_name, By.tag_name
    )
    articles = main.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "article")
    for article in articles:
        header = article.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "entry-summary")
        print(header.text)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

I cannot run this code to get the summary of each search result for the search key "test". I have changed find_elements* to `find_elements(By*, "string")`. The error just shows:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

I am new to selenium.

Comment: header is a list, so you need to specify which element of the list you want the text. eg: `header[0].text` for the first element. Maybe you want to iterate over that list, not to miss any elements.

Comment: If you know there is only one element with `class=entry-summary`, then change `find_elements()` to `find_element()`. If there are more than one elements, then you need to iterate over the list just like you do with `articles`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' - Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223011/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-click-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")

search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "s")
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #return means enter

#wait for a specific thing to exist on the page before we start looking for it
#let our driver to wait for 10 sec until EC.xxx is reached
try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main")) #By.name, By.class_name, By.tag_name
    )
    articles = main.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "article")
    for article in articles:
        header = article.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "entry-summary")
        # find_elements will produce a list - So we need to iterate over each item in that list
        for eachItem in header:
            print(eachItem.text)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

As some of the comments mention, `find_elements` will produce a list - So we need to iterate over each item in that list to print the `.text` value